# zsh - bad math expression: illegal character: ^A - when trying to read 0x01 from a file

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm reading the first four bytes of a binary file in zsh. The first 3 bytes are `0x00` and the 4th is `0x01`. I've created an array of these bytes by reading the file in as a string and then splitting it & slicing it, resulting in:

```
>  echo -n "${(j::)bytes}" | xxd
00000000: 0000 0001                                ....
```

and now I'm trying to add them up starting with the right end (4th byte) using the appropriate powers to get the sum. The trouble is, when I try to use the 4th byte in an arithmetic evaluation or an integer variable:

```
integer -i 10 b=${bytes[-1]} # This is the offending line
sum=$((sum + b * (256 ** i)))
```

I get the following error:

```
 bad math expression: illegal character: ^A
```

Which is `0x01`.

How do I tell zsh to interpret the byte as a number? I've noticed the `(#)` expansion flag, which forces an expression to be interpreted numerically and then as a character, but I'm having the opposite problem. It seems to be interpreting `0x01` as a character.

UPDATE:

I suspect the problem is that the type of the array is of characters (if zsh collections have types?) due to the fact that I created it using `(s::)` on a string of the whole file, but I'm not sure how to convert the array elements back to integers.I've tried

```
b=$(printf '%d' "$bytes[4]")
```

but this gives me a similar error. I'm able to reproduce seemingly via any of these:

```
printf '%d' $'^A'
integer b=$'^A'
```

where `^A` is made up of the two literal characters `^` and `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%d` operator for the `printf` builtin will convert a character to its numeric value, but it needs a leading quote to differentiate the input
parameter from an arithmetic expression:

```shell
>> one=$'\1'
>> typeset -p one
typeset one=$'\C-A'
>> printf '%d\n' "'$one"  # leading single quote
1
>> printf '%d\n' "' "     # quote and space
32
>> printf '%d\n' '"A'     # leading double-quote
65

>> # your input values:
>> bytes=($'\0' $'\C-@' ${(#):-0} $'\C-A')
>> typeset -p bytes
typeset -a bytes=( $'\C-@' $'\C-@' $'\C-@' $'\C-A' )
>> integer b=$(printf '%d' "'$bytes[4]")
>> print "value in b: $b"
value in b: 1
```

Note that the value in `b` is a string, even though it was declared as an `integer`. The integer typeset only changes how the variable is treated in assignments and expansions - it doesn't change the internal representation.

---

To convert an entire array of bytes, use the `-v` (assign variable) option in `printf`:

```shell
>> setopt nomultibyte
>> typeset -a bin=($'\C-@'  $'\C-C' ' ' 'A' '~' ${(#):-240})
>> typeset -a nums
>> printf -v nums %d \'${^bin}
>> typeset -p nums
typeset -a nums=( 0 3 32 65 126 240 )
```

Some of the pieces:

- `typeset -a nums` - the output array. This is declared as an array so that `printf` will assign each result to a separate array element. From the
  [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf):

  > The -v option causes the output to be stored as the value of the parameter *name*, instead of printed. If *name* is an array and the format string is reused when consuming arguments then one array element will be used for each use of the format string.
- `\'${^bin}` - this will prefix each element in the array with a single quote, using the `${^...}` [rc_expand_param](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-array-expansion-style_002c-rc) option.
- `setopt nomultibyte` - with this, shell operations will treat each byte as a single character. This isn't absolutely necessary when processing arrays of single bytes, but it ensures some consistency when displaying and assigning values.

Comment: Thanks, I learned several things from this!